# cakephp asset management speed

Tags: cakephp, plugins, themes, dispatch

I'm new to cakephp and I found this in the manual:

> It’s a well known fact that serving assets through PHP is guaranteed
>   to be slower than serving those assets without invoking PHP. And while
>   the core team has taken steps to make plugin and theme asset serving
>   as fast as possible, there may be situations where more performance is
>   required. In these situations it’s recommended that you either symlink
>   or copy out plugin/theme assets to directories in app/webroot with
>   paths matching those used by CakePHP.
>
> ```
> app/Plugin/DebugKit/webroot/js/my_file.js 
>    becomes app/webroot/debug_kit/js/my_file.js
> app/View/Themed/Navy/webroot/css/navy.css 
>    becomes app/webroot/theme/Navy/css/navy.css
> ```

Are files in plugin/webroot/asset required to be read by PHP then inserted into HTML rather than served directly by the server itself because really isn't a webroot directory that can be accessed by the http module?

The manual says soft links will speed this process up.  Does cakephp first look in /app/webroot/asset then call the dispatcher to find it in plugin/webroot/asset and read it and serve it?

Or is the process identical in how the file is found/read except cake must use the dispatcher to locate the asset if it is not in the app/webroot/asset location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serving files...

### Webservers are fastest

The [default rewrite rules](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/.htaccess) are as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

That means if the request is for a file that the webserver can see - don't talk to php just respond with the file's contents (or appropriate headers). In this circumstance there is no "Does cakephp first look in /app/webroot/asset ..." as there is no CakePHP - or PHP - involved in handling the request at all.

So, in brief that's:

```
Request 
-> webserver 
  -> check if file exists
    -> response (file contents)
```

*If a different webserver (not apache) is being used, CakePHP expects equivalent rewrite rules. It will never check if the equivalent of `app/webroot/<the current url>` exists - as the webserver should be doing that itself.*

### PHP is slow

If the request is for a file that does *not* exist in the webroot, things are much slower because quite simply there's more processes involved. Even a php script like so:

```
<?php
// example app/webroot/index.php
$path = 'server/this/file.html';
echo file_get_contents($path);
exit;
```

is slower than an equivalent request handled directly by a webserver, as that's:

```
Request 
-> webserver 
  -> check if file exists
    -> invoke php 
      -> get file contents 
    -> respond to webserver 
  -> response
```

Plus php wasn't specifically designed for serving files (like a webserver is or should be) and so is inherently slower than a webserver alone at doing so.

### CakePHP is slower

The only path that is directly web-accessible for a CakePHP project is ´app/webroot`.

For a request handled by CakePHP, even using the [Asset dispatch filter](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html) (which is a slimmed down dispatch process) - obviously  there is more logic involved, so it's slower than the bare minimum logic required to server a file with php. In brief the request becomes:

```
Request 
-> webserver 
  -> check if file exists
    -> invoke php 
      -> Bootstrap CakePHP
      -> Dispatch Request
        -> Check Dispatch filters
          -> check if request matches a configured plugin/theme file path
            -> check if file exists
          -> generate response
        -> output response
    -> respond to webserver 
  -> response
```

The difference in performance compared to letting the webserver handle the request for a static file [can be very significant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17142953/761202).

### Conclusion

Serving files with php when it's not necessary is a waste of resources, if at all possible allow the response to come from higher up the request - the webserver, a proxy or preferably the user's own browser cache (~0 latency!).